# Google Tag track popup

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, tracking

I straggle with setting up the google tag for a popup on the website. I follow the guides, but it doesnt work. There is the code from the webpage, what should i take specifically?

The webpage where i want to track from --> https://liz.solutions/
I need to track the red button 30 Tage Testversion(30 days test version). After it should be submitted, and after the desired popup shows up that i provide code for.

Thanks in advance!

```
<html data-tag-assistant-present="1657287900174"><head> <title>Widget Iframe</title> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/statics/css/w-iframe-less.css?v=1"> <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mailcheck/1.1.2/mailcheck.js"></script> <script nonce="" src="/statics/js/mj-widget-iframe.js?v=1"></script> <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.6.3/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script> </head> <body class="responsive"> <div id="error-block"> <div id="message-block"> <p class="success">Ihre Registrierung war erfolgreich. Sie erhalten in den n&amp;amp;auml;chsten Minuten eine E-Mail-Best&amp;amp;auml;tigung oder &amp;amp;uuml;berpr&amp;amp;uuml;fen Sie nach 24 Stunden Ihren Spam-Ordner und klicken Sie auf den angegebenen Link.</p> </div> </div> <script nonce=""> userPref(); </script> <div style="clear: both; display: block;"></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a iframe tag and looks like it's from MailJet.

[image]

We can not track something inside the iframe.

There is some way that can only track `Click the Iframe` but not `Click certain button in the iframe`.
https://measureschool.com/iframe-tracking/

If I investigated the wrong element and please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Do you think it would make sense to completely change that pop-up?

Comment: And is there a way how it can be tracked? thanks in advance

Comment: The best for this as I can imagine is : Try to find there is an alternative way to build the form. If you can build the form as a individual page and send it to mailjet via API or mailjet can provide only the code of form. It would be great.